# Possible to call virConnectDomainXMLToNative in libvirt-python?

Tags: python, xen, libvirt

I need to be able to export the domain's XML configs to XEN config format under libvirt using libvirt-python. Apparently to make that call, you use the following in C:

```
virConnectDomainXMLToNative

Reads a domain XML configuration document, and generates a native configuration file describing the domain. The format of the native data is hypervisor dependant.

conn:   a connection object
nativeFormat:   configuration format exporting to
domainXml:  the domain configuration to export
flags:  extra flags; not used yet, so callers should always pass 0
Returns:    a 0 terminated UTF-8 encoded native config datafile, or NULL in case of error. the caller must free() the returned value.
```

However, there is no equivalent function in Python.

I noticed you can call certain C functions in libvirt-python. I don't see that in the current list of calls, though, when I use help(libvirt). (I am using the libvirt-python package that is available with CentOS 5, BTW).

Is there a way to make that call anyway within Python and convert the domain .xml to xen config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Python API bindings page](http://libvirt.org/python.html), functions starting with `virConnect` are mapped to methods of a `virConnect` object in Python. So you should create a `virConnect` object and then call its `domainXMLToNative` method.

If that still doesn't work, you can use the [ctypes](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html) module to call functions from a shared library.

Comment: it looks like it requires that I upgrade to at least libvirt and libvirt-python 0.7x. I guess that's the way forward.